# How to show csv file data into primefaces datatable?

Tags: java, csv, jsf, primefaces, datatable

For example I have a csv file like this:

```
column1,column2,column3,column4
1,one,un,eins
2,two,deux,zwei
3,three,trois,drei
4,four,quattre,four
5,five,cinque,fuenf
6,six,six,sechs
7,seven,sept,sieben
8,eight,huit,acht
9,nine,neuf,neun
10,ten,dix,zehn
```

But the number of columns will change as I have multiple csv files. So I have used this [dynamic columns](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/columns.xhtml) and I have successfully displayed the column header of some random csv files but I am unable to display the data of the columns into primefaces data table. How I can display the content of the file?

.xhtml:

```
<p:dataTable var="attr"  value="#{newClass.a_name2}" scrollable="true" scrollWidth="50%" scrollHeight="150">
       <p:columns  width="125" value="#{newClass.columns}" var="column" >
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{column.header}" />
            </f:facet>  
            <h:outputText value="#{attr[column.property]}" />
        </p:columns>
 </p:dataTable>
```

bean :

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class NewClass implements Serializable{
private List<Attribute> a_name2;
private List<ColumnModel> columns;
private String columnTemplate;

public void settingValue {
//csv file
columnTemplate=;//setting column names.
a_name2=createFile(numberofRowsinCsvFile);
createDynamicColumns();
}
private void createDynamicColumns() {
        String[] columnKeys = getColumnTemplate().split("\t");
        columns = new ArrayList<ColumnModel>();   
        for(String columnKey : columnKeys) {
         columns.add(new ColumnModel(columnKey.toUpperCase(),columnKey));
        }
}

public String getColumnTemplate() {
        return columnTemplate;
    }

public void setColumnTemplate(String columnTemplate) {
        this.columnTemplate = columnTemplate;
    }   
public List<ColumnModel> getColumns() {
        return columns;
    }    
public void setColumns(List<ColumnModel> columns) {
        this.columns = columns;
    }
public List<Attribute> getA_name2() {
        return a_name2;
    }

 public void setA_name2(List<Attribute> a_name2) {
        this.a_name2 = a_name2;
 }
 public List createFile(int size) {
        List list = new ArrayList();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
          list.add(i);
 }

        return list;
 }
static public class ColumnModel implements Serializable {

        private String header;
        private String property;

        public ColumnModel(String header, String property) {
            this.header = header;
            this.property = property;
        }

        public String getHeader() {
            return header;
        }

        public String getProperty() {
            return property;
        }
    }

}
```

I am getting an error:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @53,70 value="#{attr[column.property]}": The class 'java.lang.Integer' does not have the property 'outlook'.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Can you show us some of your code and explain more what you have tried to fix the problem.  Also, there is a lot of repetition in your question which should be edited out.

Comment: i have updated my question. please help me.

Comment: @Gray hello sir, i have updated my question , could you help me please